# How to debug jasypt

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, encryption, jasypt

I currently have three java applications that I want to encrypt the DB passwords for. For my first app, the following syntax for jasypt works. I have an encrypted password and it can login to the db with no issues. However, my other two apps fail with an invalid/username password error.
My main question: Is there a way to debug jasypt so I can see whether or not it tried to decrypt the password specified below? Im guessing the decrypt is failing and it is trying to log in using the encrypted password. If I change the persistence.xml back to the un-encrypted password it works just fine.
Thanks for any thoughts anyone might have!

Here are my files:

jasypt password gen:

```
c:\jasypt-1.9.2\bin\encrypt input=mydbpassword password=password algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES
----ENVIRONMENT----------------

Runtime: Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.45-b08

-----ARGUMENTS-----------------
input: mydbpassword
password: password
algorithm: PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES

------OUTPUT-------------------
h+RqHWpovo5q390ID9+dTTs/9k0bmwlI
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="localDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
    <property name="connection.provider_class" value="org.jasypt.hibernate.connectionprovider.EncryptedPasswordDriverManagerConnectionProvider" />
    <property name="connection.encryptor_registered_name" value="strongHibernateStringEncryptor" />
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
    <!-- DEV -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=foo.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=db2)))" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="db2" />
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="ENC(h+RqHWpovo5q390ID9+dTTs/9k0bmwlI)" />
```

spring bean:

```
<bean id="hibernateStringEncryptor" class="org.jasypt.hibernate3.encryptor.HibernatePBEStringEncryptor">
    <property name="registeredName">
        <value>strongHibernateStringEncryptor</value>
    </property>
    <property name="algorithm">
        <value>PBEWithMD5AndTripleDES</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password>
        <value>password</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Error I received when I deploy the app:

```
2016-05-09 16:37:29,149 INFO [STDOUT] INFO [DriverManagerConnectionProvider] using driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver at URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=foo.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SID=db2)))
2016-05-09 16:37:29,149 INFO [STDOUT] INFO [DriverManagerConnectionProvider] connection properties: {user=db2, password=****,autocommit=true,release_mode=auto}
2016-05-09 16:37:29,149 INFO [STDOUT] WARN [SettingsFactory] Could not obtain conection metadata java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: Invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you've solved it by now.  But you asked for "...any thoughts anyone might have!"  In case someone else has the same problem, here are some tips.

- Attach the jasypt source code and trace it when it throws an exception related to failed authentication.  Look for the section where the password is decoded.
  If the buffer is empty, you'll know that it can't find the password.
- Rather then revealing the encrypted Oracle password as clear text in persistence.xml, you could inject your *decrypting password* ("password1") into the runtime environment, which jasypt will use to decrypt the *encrypted Oracle password ("password2") stored in a property file* installed on the classpath:

  `password2=ENC(h+RqHWpovo5q390ID9+dTTs/9k0bmwlI)`

Note that jasypt can clear the decrypted password from memory after decryption.

See:
   `org.jasypt.spring31.properties.EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

...which reads encrypted Oracle password2 from the property file, passes it to a jasypt decryptor bean which uses env var ${password1} to decode password2, placing the decrypted result into an env var ${password2}, which can then be referenced in persistence.xml:

`<property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="${password2}" />`

So, password2 begins encrypted in the property file, and ends decrypted in env var ${password2}.

You'll also need `org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor` and `org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.config.EnvironmentStringPBEConfig` which declares the algorithm and the name of the environment variable containing the *decrypting* password ("password1").

The scheme is described in detail here:
[Encrypting Properties With Jasypt](https://www.jayway.com/2008/12/09/encrypting-properties-with-jasypt/)

[Jasypt Documentation](http://jasypt.org/)

Once you think you have all this working, you should find in the log:
`EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer -Loading properties file from class path resource [your.file.properties]`

You can break it to prove the concept by adding a single character to password1.  Restart the app, and in the log you should find:

`EncryptablePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer -Loading properties file from class path resource [your.file.properties]`

Then `EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException`.

Reset password1 to what it ought to be and restart.  Decryption should work again.

Answer (score 0):

### I'd recommend you do the following to encrypt the applications

1. Download [**jasypt-1.9.3.jar**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmpOj.png) you can use Maven Jar collects
2. Access the jasypt-1.9.3.jar from maven .m folder and place it where you can run the below command.

   > **java -cp jasypt-1.9.3.jar org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI input="XYZ" password=ABC algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES**

   NOTE:

   - XYZ - Is your application password
   - ABC - Is your jasypt encryptor password
3. Below will the result of the above command

   [image: Results of above command]

   **Store the output as it will be used in our application.properties file.**
4. In your **pom.xml** file add the below dependency

   > com.github.ulisesbocchiojasypt-spring-boot2.0.0

   [image]
5. Add **@EnableEncryptableProperties** annotation to your SpringBoot startup class file as shown below.

   > @SpringBootApplication
   > @EnableEncryptableProperties
   > public class App
   > {     public static void main(String[] args) {
   > SpringApplication.run(IBpsAppApplication.class, args);  }
   >
   > }
6. Finally in your **application.properties** add the following properties.

> spring.datasource.password=ENC(/pmc1gJQHo3zEM2faLtMsw==)

> jasypt.encryptor.password=ABC